# Can I make where clause's in operator with subquery with group by same table using JpaSpecificationExecutor?

Tags: spring-data-jpa, specifications

I am using Spring Data's Repository implment JpaSpecificationExecutor.
I can make dynamic where clause with JapSpecificationExecutor's findAll method's Specification.

current code and table schema like that

**History Table**

id | message | groupId

1     'text'    1

2     'cotent'  1

3     'ttt'     2

4     'rrr'     3

```
historyRepository
                         .findAll(
                                 where(
                                         /** common */
                                         sndId(sndUId))
                                         .and(kind(kind))
                                         .and(sndIdNotNull())
                                         .and(groupTokenNotNull())
                                         /** search option */
                                         .and(searchHistory(historyRequestDto))
                                 /** order by date */
                                 , new PageRequest(0, 50, new Sort(Sort.Direction.DESC, "sndDate"))
                         )
```

I want to make my code to generate native mysql query like that

```
select * from History 
where
    id IN (
        select 
            min(id) 
        from 
            History 
        where
            kind = 4 
            and kind is not null
            and sndId is not null
            and groupToken is not null
        group by (groupToken) 
) order by sndDate desc
limit 0, 10
```

Can I generate code like that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes that should be possible.

The `findAll` method expects a `Specification` which is basically a function from

`Root`, `CriteriaQuery`, `CriteriaBuilder` to `Predicate`

https://thoughts-on-java.org/hibernate-tip-subquery-criteriaquery/ describes how to create a `x in (subquery)` condition:

Something like this should work:

```
(Root root, CriteriaQuery cq, CriteriaBuilder cb) -> {
    Subquery sub = cq.subquery(Long.class);
    Root subRoot = sub.from(History.class);
    sub.select(cb.min(subRoot.get("id")));
    sub.where(/* insert your existing conditions here */);

    // check the result of the subquery
    return cb.in(sub);
}
```

I didn't actually try it so it certainly will need some tweaking but the general idea should work.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work for me :

```java
static Specification<CashbackDetail> getCashbacksByStatusSpec(PaymentStatus paymentStatus) {
        return (root, query, criteriaBuilder) -> {

            // Jointures
            Join<CashbackDetail, Payment> paymentJoin = root.join("payment");
            Join<Payment, PaymentStatusHistory> historyJoinSet = paymentJoin.joinSet("statusSet");

            // Filtre sur le status le plus récent
            Subquery<Date> subQuery = query.subquery(Date.class);
            Root<PaymentStatusHistory> subFrom = subQuery.from(PaymentStatusHistory.class);
            subQuery.select(criteriaBuilder.max(subFrom.get("date")).as(Date.class));
            subQuery.where(criteriaBuilder.equal(historyJoinSet.get("entityId"), subFrom.get("entityId")));

            // Conditions
            Predicate status = criteriaBuilder.equal(historyJoinSet.get("status"), paymentStatus);
            Predicate date = criteriaBuilder.equal(historyJoinSet.get("date"), subQuery);

            return criteriaBuilder.and(status, date);
        };
    }
```